# Looking for a word/phrase that means childishly self-centered?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase to describe someone who thinks their own problems should supersede everyone else's, and who is childish about it, too boot.

Comment: Specifically, I want to talk about the reaction a grown child had at the death of her parents.  She was 38 when her dad passed away, and bemoaned, "What will happen to me?" because she relied on him to help her pay off frivilous debt

Comment: if you edit this comment into your question and add an example sentence with a ____ where the word fits, you will likely get reopen votes.

Answer (score 2):

Specifically regarding females, specifically in East Asia, [Princess sickness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_sickness)
refers to exactly the personality traits you describe in the question.

> **Princess sickness**, alternatively known as **princess syndrome** or **princess disease** [...] is a neologistic term used colloquially in some parts of Asia, notably Hong Kong, Macau, mainland China, South Korea, Japan and Taiwan, to describe a condition of narcissism, egocentrism and materialism in women, or "princess" behaviour. Conversely but less commonly, men with a similar outlook may be described as having "prince" sickness.
>   - Wikipedia

Comment: little princess / little prince
(from the link in the answer)

Comment: I think you had a good answer and I think it got downvoted because you didn't include the quote from your reference and you included Chinese chars, so I edited it. If you disagree with my edit you are free to revert it.

Comment: much appreciated ^_^    i'm still learning how to dodge downvotes for taking time and energy to help someone with a question